# Spring Security recreates HttpSession

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I try to configure Spring Security and I have one problem.

this is my SessionAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class SessionAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

        if (nonNull(user)) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getName(), null, singletonList(authority));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationFilter sessionFilter() {
        return new SessionAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(sessionFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/login"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

This is my IndexController:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> index(HttpSession session) {

        System.out.println(session.getId());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Inside SessionAuthenticationFilter HttpSession is correct, but when I try to get this session, I will get other session. Why? I understand that this is created Spring Security. How is it fixed?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why are you doing this in a filter? Spring Security already retrieves the stored user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ploblem could be related with this: `.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`

Accordingly with Spring Security Docs, Spring Security  will never create an `HttpSession` and it will never use it to obtain the `SecurityContext` when session creation policy is set to `STATELESS`.

Try changing policy to `SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS`

See
[Enum SessionCreationPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html)

Comment: I realized that my variant worked correct, just Spring Security changed id session for security. Thank you for you advice.

Comment: No worries, always is a pleasure helping other colleagues.